# Como fazer esse carrosel passar Verticalmente?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Galera estou tentando criar um carousel que exiba os itens verticalmente. Por exemplo ao clicar nos buttons um texto passe de cima para baixo, tentei fazer com o carrosel do bootstrap 4 más era muito ruim então agora estou tentando fazer com o owl carousel utilizando javascript, más não consegui e vim pedir ajuda aqui , na esperança de vocês poderem me ajudar. Segue o código do carrossel.  No caso abaixo o texto esta passando de lado, da direita para a esquerda e queria fazendo vir de cima para baixo.

```
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <div class="item">
              <h2">Button/h2>
              <p class="text-white"> 
texto 1
    
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h2">Button</h2>
              <p class="text-white">
    texto 2
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <h2">Button</h2>
              <p class="text-white">
    texto 3
              </p>
            </div>
    
          </div>
        </div>



<script>
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      600: {
        items: 1
      },
      1000: {
        items: 1
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  items: 1,
  nav: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
  animateIn: 'slideInUp'
});
```

Teste no Codepen: http://codepen.io/dapinitial/pen/xZaRqz

Comment: Tem também https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/animate.html

Comment: não foi não esse codigo /: